Does popen().readline block until all output is read?
I'm running an asynchronous long-running process with popen.  If I'm interested in getting all the data written to stdout, can I just do
cmd = popen(...)
for line in cmd.stdout.readline()
   ... do something with line

I'm wondering if I need to test cmd.poll() at any point, or can I just assume that once the process is done, readline will return EOF?
Update
Just to clarify, here is the code I'm currently using
 while True:
        line = cmd.stdout.readline()
        print(line)

        if not line:
            break

    stdout.append(line)


Can you make this a working program? Are you referring to os.popen? readline() will return a string holding one single output line, and for line in cmd.readline() would actually iterate the intividual characters of that line. If you keep calling readline until the input pipe is exhausted, it will start reading blank lines ("").

As for blocking, yes it will block until data (with a newline or end of file) is received. Since this is not a tty, the child process will push its data on some block size (maybe 256 to 64k - or something else, its os and config dependent).

for line in cmd.readline() appears to iterate through the lines, not the characters.  It appears to work the way I described.   I do not get blank characters when it's exhausted.  I just wanted to make sure

Are you sure you're not using cmd.readlines()? That will read all the lines, and put them into a list. It won't return until the child has exited (or closed stdout for some other reason).

You could instead use for line in cmd:. The file object in cmd is a generator, so it will return each line as it becomes available, rather than waiting for all of them. The command might still use output buffering, so the lines won't be immediately readable as they're written.

In any case, you don't need to use poll(). When the child closes stdout, you'll read EOF.

You are most likely using cmd.readlines(). One of the reasons I asked you for a working example was to clarify this. You haven't actually stated what the problem is here. One option is that you used cmd.readline() and were puzzled by the response. The problem with readlines is that it will block until the subprocess is complete and then give you a list of lines. If you want to consume line by line as its being fed by the subprocess, do for line in cmd. Even then, the pipe is block buffered, so results may be delayed.

I am using while True: line = cmd.stdout.readline() which reads 1 line at a time.  I end the loop when cmd.readline() returns empty

What I'd really like is to be able to specify a timeout, so that if readline() doesn't return in a certainly amount of time, it ends so that I can do other things and come back to waiting later

As others have said -- if you don't give us a [mre] that can be analyzed to rule out the hypothesis that the problem is stdout buffering on the part of the program you're reading from, we're generally going to assume that that is the problem (as tdelaney suggested earlier), and that the program simply isn't flushing its buffers when its stdout is going to a pipe rather than to a TTY; this delayed writing is libc default behavior, so it's what most programs do out-of-the-box.

BTW, the "doing other things at the same time" part of what you're looking for is a good use case for asyncio -- see in particular https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html

The difference is that want to retrieve the stdout in real time.  I don't want to just wait for the process to complete and then get all the stdout.  So I want to retrieve lines as they are available, but if nothing is available, I want to commit what I have so far to a db and then resume waiting.

asyncio lets you do that.


Does popen().readline block until all output is read?

No, it reads one line. It blocks until all output is read or a newline is read.

can I just do

No, that will iterate over characters of a single line. I think you meant to:
for line in iter(cmd.stdout.readline, ''):

but realy, just:
for line in cmd.stdout:


if I need to test cmd.poll() at any point

No. Note, that end of input from stdout of a process does not mean that a process has finished. These are two (unrelated) events. A process may close output before exiting. A process may exit, but there still may be data (buffered) in the pipe to read.

or can I just assume that once the process is done, readline will return EOF?

After a process is done, and everything has been read, then readline will return an empty string. See also https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects .

Thanks.  Is there a way to determine if data is available before calling readline().  Or a way to say 'read what you can in 5 seconds and then exit'?

To determine if there are data, if the stream object has an underlying file descriptor and you are on linux, you would extract the file descriptor and call select or poll. To read what you can in 5 seconds, create a queue = Queue() and spawn a separate thread that for line in cmd.stdout: queue.put(line) and then line = queue.get(timeout=5).
